Changing Image size using Macro, would like to loop it through all the worksheets
The Macro below is what I use to change the sizes of my pictures in one sheet but I would need to apply this to all my worksheets. What could I add here to make this happen?
Option Explicit
Sub ChangeAllPics()
Dim s As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    s.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    s.Width = 65
    s.Height = 65

Next s
End Sub

Would really appreciate the help!

Try this:
Option Explicit
Sub ChangeAllPics()
Dim s As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each s In ws.Shapes
        s.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        s.Width = 65
        s.Height = 65
    Next s
Next ws
End Sub


Unfortunately it runs but it does not seem to change anything here.

@ArshamGharbi ThisWorkbook means the workbook containing this code. If the sheets are in another workbook, replace ThisWorkbook with the correct workbook reference e.g Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsx") or ActiveWorkbook for the active workbook.
